# Skip a statement in a Doctrine migration if a column is present?

Tags: php, doctrine

I am working with Doctrine migrations. I just learned about the `skipIf()` method in the `AbstractMigration` class, and I would like to use it to skip over some code if a column exists.

Can someone provide an example of how I might do that?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you have the typical `Schema` class in your method, you can do something like this:

```
public function up(Schema $schema)
{
    if (!$schema->getTable('your_table')->hasColumn('your_column')) {
        // do your code
    }
}
```

Or, if you want to use the `skipIf` you should be able to do the following though I have not tested.

```
public function up(Schema $schema)
{
    $this->skipIf(
        $schema->getTable('your_table')->hasColumn('your_column'), 
        'Skipping because `your_column` exists'
    );
}
```